# Telerik RadChart tooltip not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, radchart

I want to display the amount in y-axis when I put the mouse on the bar graph.

```
<telerik:RadChart ID="RadChartYearComparison" runat="server" SeriesPalette="SeriesPalette1" DefaultType="Bar" Skin="Web20"
    IntelligentLabelsEnabled="true" AutoTextWrap="true" AutoLayout="true" Width="700px" Legend-Appearance-Border-Visible="false" >
    <Series>
        <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Current Year" Type="Bar">
            <Appearance>
                <TextAppearance Border-Visible="false">
                </TextAppearance>
                <FillStyle MainColor="Blue">
                </FillStyle>
                <Border Visible ="false" />
            </Appearance>
        </telerik:ChartSeries>
        <telerik:ChartSeries Name="Previous Year" Type="Bar">
            <Appearance>
                <FillStyle MainColor="Green">
                </FillStyle>
                <Border Visible ="false" />
            </Appearance>
        </telerik:ChartSeries>
    </Series>

    <CustomPalettes>
        <telerik:Palette Name="SeriesPalette1">
            <Items>
                <telerik:PaletteItem MainColor="Blue" SecondColor="Blue"/>
                <telerik:PaletteItem MainColor="Green" SecondColor="Green">
                </telerik:PaletteItem>
                <telerik:PaletteItem MainColor="Red" SecondColor="Red">
                </telerik:PaletteItem>
                <telerik:PaletteItem MainColor="#F88017" SecondColor="#F88017">
                </telerik:PaletteItem>
                <telerik:PaletteItem MainColor="Green" SecondColor="Green">
                </telerik:PaletteItem>
                <telerik:PaletteItem MainColor="DarkOrchid" SecondColor="DarkOrchid">
                </telerik:PaletteItem>
                <%--<telerik:PaletteItem MainColor="Yellow" ></telerik:PaletteItem>--%>
            </Items>
        </telerik:Palette>
    </CustomPalettes>
    <%-- <PlotArea>
        <XAxis DataLabelsColumn="MonthName"></XAxis>
    </PlotArea>--%>
</telerik:RadChart>
<telerik:RadToolTipManager ID="RadToolTipManager1" runat="server" Animation="Slide"
Position="TopCenter" EnableShadow="true">
</telerik:RadToolTipManager>
```

When I put the mouse over a bar graph, it doesn't display the exact amount.
I am not getting the tooltip when hover on bars. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/chartandtooltip/defaultcs.aspx?product=chart.

You will see there is also some server code required to generate the regions (i.e., the image map) that the tooltips will attach to. Then, the tooltip manager needs AutoTooltipify=true.

The easier approach is to use RadHtmlChart as it has built-in tooltips. You can see them in action here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/charttypes/barchart/defaultcs.aspx.

You can see how to fine-tune them here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/functionality/clienttemplates/defaultcs.aspx.